# Objective-C background music

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

I want to know how to add background music to my app.
My code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Jaunty Gumption" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
    backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [backgroundMusic play];
}
```

But when I launch the app nothing happens and I don't know why.
I have included the AVFoundation an AudioToolbox frameworks.
Any help would be appreciated. :)
Thanks Matis

Comment: Is `backgroundMusic == nil`, perhaps?

Comment: No I'm sorry but it does not change anything.

Comment: What happens if you assign the audio player to a property instead of a local variable? Maybe ARC is cleaning it up at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: When I type     for (int x = 0;x==0;){
    [backgroundMusic play];
    }  instead of [backgroundMusic play]; the music plays but the screen keeps black and my play button doesn't appear.

Comment: -1 for not checking your error parm.

Comment: @HotLicks What is my error parm? I'm quite new to Objective-C.

Comment: The one that begins `error:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC is destroying your audio player before it gets any chance to output audio. When an audio player is about to be destroyed, it stops playing audio. Assign it to a strong property instead of a local variable, like so:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *musicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Jaunty Gumption"
                                               withExtension:@"mp3"];
    self.backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile
                                                                  error:nil];
    self.backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.backgroundMusic play];
}

@end
```

Doing this will keep the audio player alive at least as long as the view controller.

Comment: Thanks but when I use your code I get the error: No visible @interface for 'NSBundle' declares the selector'urlForResource:withExtension:' and the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'backgroundMusic'

Comment: @MatisDS My bad, fixed that now. When you want to refer to a property, prepend its name with `self.`, e.g. `self.backgroundMusic`. I recommend you read [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I have changed my code and now I am getting the error: No visible @interface for 'NSBundle' declares the selector 'urlForResource:withExtension:'

Comment: @MatisDS It's `URLForResource:withExtension:`, not `urlForResource:withExtension:`.